# Struggling to find a way to interpret ASCII ACS/EPF files from Post Office

Tags: csv, ascii, acs, epf

We are receiving these files from the post office that provide address update information. I'm told they are in ASCII format. However, I cant seem to find any sort of delimiter in order to try to convert this into a format I can use for updating our mailing list (which is stored in a mysql database).

I'd like to convert them into a CSV format. But maybe one of you guys can tell by looking at a sample file if theres something obvious that I'm missing.

http://cloud.noahyamen.com/121B2A3v2A1m

Comment: Please post some sample data and whatever code you have tried here.

Comment: Read the USPS guide on the [New ACS Format](https://ribbs.usps.gov/acs/newACSformat/ACSFileFormatTechnicalGuide.pdf).  It is fixed width...

Answer (score 0):

The header is a 702 character fixed with format with the following fields:

[image]

The records are also 702 characters and are described in the [ACS document](https://ribbs.usps.gov/acs/newACSformat/ACSFileFormatTechnicalGuide.pdf).

You can read more about it at the USPS site for the ACS file format [HERE](https://ribbs.usps.gov/index.cfm?page=newACSformat)